# Why does signal connection invalidate the SocketClient object?

Tags: c++, glib, gio, libsigc++, glibmm

I am trying to make a TCP / TLS connection with the SocketClient class from Gio via giomm.

Everything was fine, until I connected to the `SocketClient::event_signal ()` signal with `sigc::ptr_fun ()`.

Here is a trimmed down example code that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <giomm/error.h>
#include <giomm/init.h>
#include <giomm/networkaddress.h>
#include <giomm/socketclient.h>
#include <glibmm/main.h>
#include <iostream>

void socket_client_event (Gio::SocketClientEvent event,
              const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::SocketConnectable> &connectable,
              const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::IOStream> &connection) {
}

int main () {
  auto loop = Glib::MainLoop::create ();
  Gio::init ();
  auto network_address = Gio::NetworkAddress::create ("www.example.org", 437);
  auto socket_client = Gio::SocketClient::create ();
  socket_client->set_tls (true);
  socket_client->signal_event ().connect (sigc::ptr_fun (&socket_client_event));
  Glib::RefPtr<Gio::SocketConnection> socket_connection;
  try {
    socket_connection = socket_client->connect (network_address);
  }
  catch (const Gio::TlsError &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what (). c_str () << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  catch (const Gio::Error &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what (). c_str () << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  loop->run ();
}
```

When the `connect ()` method is called I get this console output:

```
(process:9046): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_socket_connection_connect: assertion 'G_IS_SOCKET_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(process:9046): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:9046): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:9046): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

And then a segmentation fault makes the program die.

I have switched on G_DEBUG=all and stopped at the first error, but according to the backtrace this is somewhere inside the `connect ()` method.

The curious thing is that commenting out the source line that connects the signal handler fixes the problem.

So what am I doing wrong when connecting the signal here? Why is the socket client invalid after connecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [seems to be a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glibmm/issues/28) in the reference counting in either glibmm or gio.

If I reference the objects manually in the event the problem goes away:

```
void socket_client_event (Gio::SocketClientEvent event,
              const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::SocketConnectable> &connectable,
              const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::IOStream> &connection) {
  // Workaround for reference counting problems
  if (connectable) {
    connectable->reference ();
  }
  if (connection) {
    connection->reference ();
  }
}
```